# Unexpected Output with tkinter Entry

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter

My code intends to validate an Entry box.  It works fine until I input a `0` value. Afterwards the validation does not work anymore.

Does anybody have an explanation for what is happening?

My Code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
 
def correct(inp):
    if (len(inp) <= 1) and (inp.isdigit()):
        if ((int(inp) > 0) and (int(inp) < 10)):
            if (inp != '0'):
                return True
    elif inp is "":
        return True
    else:
        return False
 
e = Entry(root)
e.place(x = 50, y = 50)
reg = root.register(correct)
e.config(validate = "key", validatecommand = (reg, "%P"))
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "it completely breaks the code" is not an accurate enough description of your problem. Please describe it more clearly: what did you expect vs what did you get?

Comment: may i ask wat is `inp`?

Comment: @CoolCloud inp is the input from the tkinter entry

Comment: @nagyl but how is it possible? without any variable reference?

Comment: @CoolCloud he sets it with the config function of the entry box. The validate stuff below the declaration of the entry. It is working fine until you input a 0.

Comment: @nagyl beyond my level atm, thanks doe :D

Comment: @CoolCloud Consider it working, and focus on the correct function :D

Comment: It does not break my code, doe i inputed 0, any error codes ? please update the Q with it

Comment: It did broke in my PC. @CoolCloud

Comment: He forgot to return a bool value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were an error while validating your input is between 0-9. Also treat `inp` as an int after validating it is not an empty `string`!

The error seems to be if the input is within the range, and not a zero, you return True, but if it is a 0, nothing happens, thus this function is required to return a boolean value.

```
    if ((int(inp) > 0) and (int(inp) < 10)): #within the range
            if (inp != '0'): # if not a zero
                return True  # return true
            # there is no else statement, no return if inp is 0
```

Working code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
 
 
def correct(inp):
    if not inp.strip():
        return True
    if len(inp) == 1 and inp.isdigit() and 0 <= int(inp) < 10:
        if (int(inp) != 0):
            print('Not a zero')
            return True
        else:
            print('This is a zero')
            return True
    return False
        
e = Entry(root)
e.place(x = 50, y = 50)
reg = root.register(correct)
e.config(validate = "key", validatecommand = (reg, "%P"))
 
root.mainloop()
```